# How to find which domain in my VPS triggered a DDoS attack with WP xmlrpc

Tags: attacks, ddos

Today, my data center suspended my VPS for DDoS attack reasons. They say one of my clients, that has WordPress website, started a DDOS attack to another websites using xmlrpc. But I don't know which of my customers abused!

Please tell me how I can find which of my clients started the DDoS attack, because I must terminate then from my VPS.

Also please tell me how I can prevention from same issue if it happens again.

My VPS have CPanel and WHM and SSH access, OS is Centos.

Comment: the logs should tell you where the traffic came from.

Comment: So how i view all logs of my websites? @schroeder

Comment: That's a question for SuperUser, and it depends on the technology you are using.

Comment: @schroeder I'm using WHM and i have root access